# What does 'incompatible' in go.mod mean, will it cause harm?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using [goczmq](https://github.com/zeromq/goczmq) in my project, something like next:

**main.go:**

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/zeromq/goczmq"
)

func main() {
}
```

And more, I'm using golang 1.12 with gomod to manage my project.

See next, I use `go mod init xxx`, and when build, it downloads goczmq automatically for me and add dependency to `go.mod`, but has `incompatible` in it. (But for other library I may get something like `github.com/kolo/xmlrpc v0.0.0-20190717152603-07c4ee3fd181`)

**go.mod:**

```
module pigeon

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.1.0+incompatible
)
```

From some discussion (for other library), e.g. [this](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/294), it seems the library owner should do something to support golang 1.12? But in my case, all things works fine just a `incompatible` there make me a little worried (I mean all seems ok now, but some day when I use an api which I never used before, there will be hidden bomb there...?)

**So my question:**

Should I worry about this, or this is just as expected?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`+incompatible` means the dependency has a semver major version of 2 or higher and is not a Go module yet (it doesn't have go.mod in its source code).

Comment: But https://github.com/kolo/xmlrpc also not have go.mod, but as mentioned in my post, it did not show incompatible.

Comment: I've edited to anser to include that `+incompativle` is only used for v2+. It's incompatible since a "proper" Go module would have a …`/v4` in the module name if it was "v4.1.0".

Comment: Also see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-a-module-consume-a-v2-package-that-has-not-opted-into-modules-what-does-incompatible-mean

Comment: Will that cause any issue in future? if go.mod does not exist?

Answer (score 126):

Accepted answer is correct, but really not friendly for me who just get in touch with go module. I made some investigation base on the answer & make a conclusion base on [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) as next, in case anyone needed:

Standard commands like go build or go test will automatically add new dependencies as needed to satisfy imports (updating go.mod and downloading the new dependencies). But there are several different situations which will result in the different version selections:

1. If a repository has not opted in to modules but has been tagged with valid semver tags, meanwhile, it's v0/v1 module, see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-a-module-consume-a-package-that-has-not-opted-in-to-modules):

   **not opted in to modules**: means no `go.mod` in source tree

   **valid semver tags**: means the repo use git tag to tagged as something like `vX.Y.Z`

   **v0/v1 module**: means the value of major version(that is X) is 0 or 1, e.g. v0.1.0, v1.2.3

   Then, it will use a `pseudo-version`, something like `github.com/kolo/xmlrpc v0.0.0-20190717152603-07c4ee3fd181`
2. If a repository has not opted in to modules but has been tagged with valid semver tags, meanwhile, it's a v2+ module, see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-a-module-consume-a-v2-package-that-has-not-opted-into-modules-what-does-incompatible-mean):

   **v2+ module**: means the value of major version(that is X) is >=2,e g. v4.1.0

   Then, it will show as `incompatible`, something like `github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.1.0+incompatible`
3. If a repository has already opted in to modules, but not have been tagged with valid semver tags:

   Then, it will behave as 1, use `pseudo-version`.
4. If a repository has already opted in to modules, and has been tagged with valid semver tags, meanwhile, it's a v0/v1 module:

   Then, it will behave normally like `github.com/stretchr/testify v1.3.0`
5. If a repository has already opted in to modules, and has been tagged with valid semver tags, meanwhile, it's a v2+ module:

   Then, when import in sourcecode, we need add `/vN` at the end, e.g., `import "github.com/my/mod/v4"`, and in `go.mod` it will behave like `github.com/my/mod/v4 v4.1.0`

Comment: for #5, does this means we have to create a new folder or project for `/v4` (since this is a github repository) for it? Or is it that we just add the suffix `/v4` to just indicate its version is v2+ without actual folder?

Comment: No physical folder needed. Give you a example: This project https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/go.mod#L9 need to use `github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22 v22.0.0`, but next is the project `coreos`: https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd, you could see it did not have a folder `v22.0.0`, just have it in module name: https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/master/go.mod#L1

Comment: What do you mean by "opted in to modules"? That there is a go.mod file or something else?

Comment: @S.Yacko YES, with `go.mod`, more precisely `using go modules`, see https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules

Answer (score 7):

The module name should have been github.com/zeromq/goczmq/v4 instead of [github.com/zeromq/goczmq](https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fzeromq~2Fgoczmq/info?version=v4.2.0%2Bincompatible) for versions v4 and above (v4.1.0, v4.2.0, etc).

Since github.com/zeromq/goczmq has not adopted Go modules correctly, the go get will fail if Go 1.13 is used and the GOPROXY is set to direct or to some other server that does not host this file -

```
    go get github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go get github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: invalid version: +incompatible suffix not allowed: module contains a go.mod file, so semantic import versioning is required
```

More details mentioned under the '**Version validation**' section here - https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#modules

Note - GoSUMDB also won't have such entries so even if you set the GOPROXY to a server that hosts this file and if GOSumDB is enabled, then you will get something like this -

```
    ➜  ~ export GOPROXY=https://gocenter.io
    ➜  ~ go get github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: downloading github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    verifying github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: reading https://gocenter.io/sumdb/sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: 404 Not Found
```

The correct solution will be to follow up with the module author to make sure that they are adopting Go modules correctly by adding a suffix to the module name.

There is a workaround but have to check if it's working by design i.e. point GOPROXY to a server that hosts this file and then use GOPRIVATE to exclude this specific module version from GoSumDB validation -

```
    root@715c3b39bb12:/go# export GOPROXY=https://gocenter.io 
    root@715c3b39bb12:/go# unset GOPRIVATE

    root@715c3b39bb12:/go# go get github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: finding github.com/zeromq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: downloading github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    verifying github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: reading https://gocenter.io/sumdb/sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible: 404 Not Found

    root@715c3b39bb12:/go# export GOPRIVATE=github.com/zeromq/goczmq

    root@715c3b39bb12:/go# go get github.com/zeromq/goczmq@v4.2.0+incompatible

    go: downloading github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    go: extracting github.com/zeromq/goczmq v4.2.0+incompatible
    # pkg-config --cflags  -- libczmq libzmq libsodium
    Package libczmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libczmq.pc'
```

However, will still recommend reaching out to the module author to fix the module name in their go.mod file.