# Why is a "+compatible" dependency OK for `go build` but not for `go list -m all`?

Tags: go

I tried to read the source code of tidb-lightning with GoLand. But it failed to index the project complaining with the following error message:

```
go: finding github.com/pingcap/tidb v3.0.4+incompatible
go: finding github.com/pingcap/tidb v3.0.4+incompatible
go list -m: github.com/pingcap/tidb@v3.0.4+incompatible: invalid version: +incompatible suffix not allowed: module contains a go.mod file, so semantic import versioning is required
```

But when I tried `make lightning` to build the binaries everything's OK.

I've googled the error message but can not find an existing solution. But I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355929/what-incompatible-in-go-mod-mean-will-it-make-harm) and guessed that it had something to do with semver, so I updated the dependency to some v1 version and now GoLand can index it.

I wonder if this dependency is valid at all, why does `go list -m all` fail while `go build` succeed?