# Are Go modules really usable today given third party "incompatible" modules?

Tags: go, semantic-versioning, go-modules

I am new to Go and trying to create my first program. Following the various getting started & tutorials I create a new module, which for my purpose needs to have a dependency on this module:

```
github.com/timescale/promscale@0.6.2
```

My problem is that the module has dependencies that have not "properly adopted" the semantic versioning approach.

```
go list -e -m all
...
k8s.io/client-go v12.0.0+incompatible
...
```

reports 37 such modules... so contacting the module author to have them adopt SIV, as I have seen suggested, will not be an option.

Am I missing something, or should I simply completely give up on using modules for this new project?

Comment: You should not give up, modules are the preferred and suggested way. Having an "incompatible" dependency doesn't mean it does not work. See [What does 'incompatible' in go.mod mean, will it cause harm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355929/what-does-incompatible-in-go-mod-mean-will-it-cause-harm)

Comment: I had seen that post, and I assumed the opposite conclusion. It mentions that go get will not work, and that I should contact the module author. If the solution is to use one of the 5 workarounds mentioned in the second post, I’ll definitely give up on modules, the level of complexity just doesn’t make any sense for a 5 line hello world project.

Comment: You can’t really give up on modules, since they are required for working with any dependencies, nearly all of which use modules.

Answer (score 2):

> Are Go modules really usable today given third party "incompatible" modules?

Yes.

> Am I missing something

Maybe: This "+incompabtible" is not a sign of failure.

> or should I simply completely give up on using modules for this new project?

No, of course not.

Comment: It is failing. Go get -m all reports an error instead of the list of dependencies. If your suggestion is to try to set up proxies or the similar workarounds mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355929/what-does-incompatible-in-go-mod-mean-will-it-cause-harm I will definitely pass on that feature.

Comment: @franck102 I doubt the problem is on the side of the dependecies. E.g. k8s.io/client-go has properly adopted Go modules and explains in detail what to do to get it running https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/v0.22.4/INSTALL.md#troubleshooting .  Maybe you should update some dependencies on _your_ side? Also: Your question stated that `go get list -e -m all` reports problem. Now `go get list` is nonsense and probably should be `go list`. Start with these things, not fancy proxie stuff.

Comment: Indeed I meant "go list -m all", I have edited the post. That breaks Goland dependency handling which apparently uses go lsit under the hood , I managed to fix that using GOFLAGS=-e. I was able to get go build to work after a couple manual "go get" suggested by the command.

Comment: `go get` adds dependencies. Without explicitly (what you call "manual") adding them they are just missing. This is not a problem of modules.

Comment: I meant "go list -m all" as well in my initial comment, sorry. W.r.t. k8s.io/client-go the issue I assume comes from how timescale/promscale or some other transitive dependency requires it, which is something I don't control.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and comments, it seems that:

1. New project should use modules, +incompatible dependencies will come up but that is fine
2. This [FAQ entry](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-a-module-consume-a-v2-package-that-has-not-opted-into-modules-what-does-incompatible-mean) has it right, just read the first 2 lines and keep "Additional Details" for a rainy day
3. `go list -m all` won't behave as described in all the tutorials if +incompatible dependencies exist, it will choke on the first incompatible module instead.

`go list -m -e all` seems to work as expected.

If you are using Goland, using `GOFLAGS=-e` seems to make dependency resolution work despite +incompatible modules. This may well have side effects that I am not aware of.